# regex test() vs Match() - incorrect results on second run with test()

Tags: javascript, regex

2nd calls to a function using test() with regex is returning different results for some reason.   I can't see what is causing the difference.  I thought maybe it had something to do with object reference, but can't trace it.

If I change the function to use match()   (See second function matchTrees() ). It works find for both the first and second call to the function.   Snippet with console output below.

```js
var trees = [
    {"regX" : /alder$/gi,"id":"Alder"},
    {"regX" : /elm/gi,"id":"Elm"},
    {"regX" : /ash/gi,"id":"Ash"}
    ];

function testTrees(treeArray){
    var matchedTrees = [];
    var i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < treeArray.length; i++) { 
        for (j = 0; j < trees.length; j++) {
             if(trees[j].regX.test(treeArray[i])){
             //if(treeArray[i].match(trees[j].regX)){
                matchedTrees.push(trees[j]);

                break;    
            }    
        }        
    }
    return matchedTrees;
}

function matchTrees(treeArray){
    var matchedTrees = [];
    var i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < treeArray.length; i++) { 
        for (j = 0; j < trees.length; j++) {
             //if(trees[j].regX.test(treeArray[i])){
             if(treeArray[i].match(trees[j].regX)){
                matchedTrees.push(trees[j]);

                break;    
            }    
        }        
    }
    return matchedTrees;
}

var treeArray = ["Elm", "Ash"];
var firstresult;
var secondresult;

console.log("run twice with test()");
firstresult = testTrees(treeArray);
console.log(JSON.stringify(firstresult));

secondresult = testTrees(treeArray);
console.log(JSON.stringify(secondresult));

console.log("run twice with match()");
firstresult = matchTrees(treeArray);
console.log(JSON.stringify(firstresult));

secondresult = matchTrees(treeArray);
console.log(JSON.stringify(secondresult));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: That looks like the index with the global flag was the problem - thanks.
Interesting that match() treats the global flag differently.